# php displays 'Empty' even when all fields are actually not

Tags: php, arrays, oop

In this form I created, it checks if the fields are set and are empty. I made a class with two methods, `areSet()` as `isset()`, and `areEmpty()` as `empty()`. In the `areEmpty()` method, it is supposed to display "Empty" if all the fields are empty, but even when all the fields are filled up, it still displays "Empty". Is it because of the `implode()` function that I used? I need someone's help to point out the wrong with my code.

HTML

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="password" name="passwordAgain" placeholder="Confirm password" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

validate.php

```
<?php

require 'include/class.php';

if(Input::areSet('firstname','lastname','email','username','password','passwordAgain')) {
    if(Input::areEmpty('firstname','lastname','email','username','password','passwordAgain')) {
        echo 'Empty';
    } else {
        echo 'Not empty';
    }
}
```

class.php

```
<?php

class Input {
    // isset()
    public static function areSet(...$fields) {
        $setFieldsArray = [];

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $setFieldsArray[] = $_POST[$field];
        }

        return isset($setFieldsArray);
    }

    // empty()
    public static function areEmpty(...$fields) {
        $emptyFieldsArray = [];

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $emptyFieldsArray[] = empty($_POST[$field]);
        }

        return implode(' || ', $emptyFieldsArray);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're doing there by setting an array and then returning an imploded array; but just loop through the `$fields`, check if the associated `$_POST` variable is empty and return `true` if so and at the end `false` if none are empty:

```
public static function areEmpty(...$fields) {

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if(empty($_POST[$field])) {
            return true; // something was empty
        }
    }
    return false; // none were empty
}
```

You'll have issues with `areSet()` as well, because you loop `$fields` and set an array element of `$setFieldsArray` and then return if it is empty, which it will never be empty because you create array elements in it.

Comment: So the `areSet()` method must have the same functionality as `areEmpty()`?